# C++ - A 3-d data structure - should I use vector of pointers or vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have to maintain a data structure which is 3 dimensional. So let us say it's dimensions are :- l x m x n. In the program that I wish to write l and  m will be known since the time the data structure is being constructed . But n has to be dynamic throughout runtime. And n may be different for the different vectors in the grid lxm. (Once this structure is created I never intend to destruct it as I will be needing it throughout).

For the moment let us assume it's a 2-dimensional data structure that I wish to make, should I make a vector<vector<int>> or a vector<vector<int>*> ? Also I know how I might initialise the vector to the required size in the first case, i.e I might do something like :-

```
vector<vector<int> > A(m)
```

to initialise the size of the outer dimension to m. But in the second case, once I have created a vector of pointers to vectors, how do I create the vectors to which the pointers point.

Carrying this to the 3-d case, should I use , 
a vector<vector<vector>> or a vector<vector<vector*>> or some other combination ?

Please, suggest any changes so that I may reframe the question if it's not framed properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better using a single `vector` (and not nested ones), since the memory is guaranteed to be contiguous in this case and your code will be way faster due to no cache misses. In this case, you need to map from 3D (2D) to 1D and vice-versa, but this is pretty straightforward

for 2D:

```
(x,y) <-> y*DIM_X + x;
```

for 3D:

```
(x,y,z) <-> z*(DIM_Y*DIM_X) + y*DIM_X + x;
```

If you really insist to use nested vectors, you can do something like:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
using vec = std::vector<T>; // to save some typing

int main()
{
    // creates a 5 x 4 x 3 vector of vector of vector
    vec<vec<vec<double>>> v{5, vec<vec<double>>{4, vec<double>{3}}};
}
```

**EDIT**

Responding to your latest edit: use

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v{DIM_X*DIM_Y, std::vector<double>};
// address (x,y,z)
v[y*DIM_X+x, z] = val_x_y_z;
```

If you further happen to know the dimensions of the inner vectors, you can preallocate memory for them using [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). This will speed things up since there won't be any (slow) re-allocations.

Comment: So you mention this with respect to the 2-d case or the 3-d case? I mean this formula.

Comment: I still have some confusion. Let us consider the 2-d case. I create a single vector :- vector<int> A  ? How should I insert elements into it ? the outer dimension is fixed, but inner is dynamic.

Comment: @ameyask86 You create a vector of size `DIM_X x DIM_Y`, e.g.`std::vector<double> v(DIM_X * DIM_Y);`, then insert into it via the formula, `v[y*DIM_Y+x] = val_x_y;` Do you plan to change the `DIM_Y` dimension afterwards?

Comment: Yes, the second dimension is changeable. As I mentioned, it is dynamic. Hence I am confused how to insert elements. Not only is it dynamic, the vectors will be of different sizes . For example I can have the 2-d structure as : - {3,8},{1,2,3},{4,6,7} . In this example the outer dimension is of size 3, the other dimension is changeable, for first vector its 2, for second its 3 and for third its 3. The structure may later become :- {3,8},{1,2,3},{4,6,7,9,11} , i.e 2 more elements were added to the 3rd vector.

Comment: @ameyask86 So do you have something like a matrix or just a vector of vectors, the latter of various dimensions? If this is the case, then you you need to use a `vector<vector<>>`, there is no other way. But in this case you shouldn't say that you have a `L x M x N` structure, since you really have something like a rectangular grid that contains "columns" of variable length. In this case you can speed up the program a bit by using a `vector<vector>` (instead of `vector<vector<vector>>`, translate 2D to 1D, but use the inner vector for the variable length columns.

Comment: @ameyask86 So in the example above with 5 x 4 x 3, use a `std::vector<std::vector<double> v<5*4, std::vector<double>>`, and address the `x,y` coordinates via the formula, then keep the `z` coordinate variable. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes I was sloppy to use lxmxn . So in the 2-d case where I have a vector<vector <int> >, I am concerned if inserting elements into the inner vectors will lead to loss of speed. As it will always lead to reallocation of memory in the entire 2-d vector ? Wouldnt it be better to use a vector of pointers ?

Comment: @ameyask86 No, it is basically the same as using a vector of pointers. Vectors themselves use a pointer internally, and there should be no (significant) speed difference (C++ standard library is constructed with the zero-overhead principle in mind, so containers should be as fast as the C-like code). If you know in advance the length of the inner vectors, you can preallocate memory for them with [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). This will speed things up since there will be no more reallocations.

Comment: Yes  now the issue is clear . So can you give an example when vector <vector<int>* > is better than vector <vector <int> > ?

Comment: @ameyask86 you mean probably a `std::vector<int*>` vs `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Both should have similar performances. A `std::vector<T>` is using internally a `T*`.

Comment: Yes I mean , given an object T, which is better , a vector of vector of T or a vector of pointer to vector of T. Is this what you meant too ?

Comment: @ameyask86 A vector of pointer to vector of int is rarely a good idea. Use either a vector of vector of int or a vector of pointer to int. Preferably a vector of vector of int.

Answer (score 0):

No, use a proper multidimensional array: Boost MultiArray http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;
}
```